# Using 3rd party audio units (.component) in application

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

Can I use 3rd party audio units with extension .component in application, copying AU to project?

I know, that I can copy .component to ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/ and then get all components by

```
AudioComponentDescription descr = {0};

NSArray *components = [[AVAudioUnitComponentManager sharedAudioUnitComponentManager] componentsMatchingDescription: descr];
```

but I need to use specific au without asking user to download this au first.